# How to reuse the same UIView among different tabs?

Tags: iphone, uiview

In a tab bar application with a UIWebView for each tab, I want to show a loading screen that is displayed in webViewDidStartLoad and then gets hidden in webViewDidFinishLoad. Right now I have a UIView in every nib file, but I was wondering what could be a better way to reuse just one UIView.

Thanks!

Comment: The purpose of the UITabBarController is to handle multiple views. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/SpecialViews/SpecialViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH10-SW13

Comment: I don't think you'd gain much by reusing one little view (unless it's a full-screen-sized loading view).

Comment: Daniel, each "loading view" has an activity indicator and some text, and if the loading fails a button for refreshing. Thus it would be handy to reuse the same if possible..

Comment: Evan, do you find something "bad" in terms of user experience? Each tab will be pointing to a different URL - I just don't know if there is a way to create this loading view and use it in all the other controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one possibility.

If you want to do that you have to play with the window and why not your application delegate.

Just add a loading view as an application delegate attribute. And then create two functions in the appDelegate

```
-(void)startLoading
{
[self.loadingView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and

```
-(void)stopLoading
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.loadingView];
}
```

And that's it ! Just invoke the methods when you needs them.

E.G :

```
[((AppDelegateClassName *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) startLoading];
```